# Android Java FCM not generates token

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using two Firebase's services in my app. It is realtime database and now I want to implement FCM. The first one works great but about FCM I cannot even generate token. Method onNewToken is not called but I did not generated it yet (I do not see this in console where usually we can send test notifications).

So the question is: are there any special steps that needs to be done if I want to implement those two services in my Android app?

I do everything what is written in tutorials also verified all solutions in Stckoverflow regarding not generating token but nothing works.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue with dependency version.